# Create blocks of text using iteration and String.Format

Tags: python, cgi, python-3.4

I can do this:

```
>>>some_string = 'this is {0} a {1}'
>>>print(some_string.format('totally', 'string'))

>>>this is totally a string
```

What I want to do is kind of form a html list like that. Is there any way I can do **something like...**

```
my_list_items = ['<li>One</li>', '<li>Two</li>', '<li>Three</li>']
my_list = """<ol>
                    {list}
             </ol>"""
print(my_list).format(list=my_list_items)
```

and get

```
<ol>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ol>
```

The rationale being; I'm writing a small cgi app for my school. I would rather be able to keep template html pages and insert the right values when the cgi script calls the page in the manner below, than have a billion `print` calls in the cgi file itself, as that's scrappy and difficult to debug.

```
group = '11bg/En1'
AP = 'AP1'

def process_input(group, AP):
    """
    Any processing necessary, followed by calling the template and inserting the values
    """
    return read_file('pages/group_page.html').format(group=group, AP=AP)

print(process_input(group, AP))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **instantly** realised I was being an idiot. Just turn the list into a string of course.

Comment: Agree, `join` to the rescue :-)